# Design Pattern /ListBox.Items.Count

Tags: c#, winforms

i built an Winform application with Pcapdot.Net DLL's that take Pcap file and play all the file packets into the machine network card.

recently i have notice that all my main form (where all the buttons clicks\events) is a mess, i putt all the method inside those function and the code looks complicated and it's hard to understand so i started to rearrange this code.

because my application has Listbox where all the played files is inside i put all this play function inside the Play button for example: i have loop over my Listbox.Items.Count and inside i am handle this files. now i want to do something different and this is my question:

is it common way to define class that handle this Play function and from the main form every time that file added to my Listbox just fire up the event `ControlAdded` or after remove file `ControlRemoved` and put this files into my class who has List that hold this file ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be better off rearranging it more like this (to separate the business logic from your UI):

- Have a public method inside your Form class that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which is the list of files, called something like `SelectedFiles()`.
- Make a public `event` property for the "Play" button which is raised when the user clicks the "Play" button, called something like `PlayClicked`.
- Make a "controller" class which is responsible for creating and showing the form.

Your controller class would attach to the `PlayClicked` event. The controller's handler for `PlayClicked` would call the form's `SelectedFiles()` method to get the list of files, and would then do whatever it needs to do.

I would even consider wrapping the handling code for the selected files into another class called something like `SelectedFileHandler` and put the logic for handling the files into that, perhaps in a method called `HandleFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)`.

Then the "controller" class would still be hooked up to the `PlayClicked` event, but it would use the `SelectedFileHandler.HandleFiles()` method to handle the files.

Does this make some sense to you? I could be misunderstanding what you're looking for.

I'm basically saying that you should use a [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or a [Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter) architecture.

Comment: @user2214609 Unfortunately I don't have time to write a code sample just now, but have a look at [my answer to this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605161/how-to-make-form1-label-text-change-when-checkbox-on-form2-is-checked/15605436#15605436) - I posted some sample code which should show you how to create the public button clicked event and respond to it in a controller.